# What are the most common CPU architectures and system platforms for personal computers?

Tags: node.js, operating-system, cpu-architecture

NodeJ has built-in methods for detecting the machine it is running on:

`process.arch` returns the operating system CPU architecture. Possible values:

- `arm` - 32-bit  Advanced RISC Machine
- `arm64` - 64-bit  Advanced RISC Machine
- `ia32` - 32-bit Intel Architecture
- `mips` - 32-bit Microprocessor
- `mipsel` - 64-bit Microprocessor
- `ppc` - PowerPC Architecture
- `ppc64` - 64-bit PowerPC Architecture
- `s390` - 31-bit The IBM System/390
- `s390x` - 64-bit The IBM System/390
- `x32` - 32-bit extended systems
- `x64` - 64-bit extended systems
  https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processarch

`process.platform` returns the operating system platform. Possible values:

- `aix` - IBM AIX platform
- `darwin` - Darwin platform(MacOS, IOS etc)
- `freebsd` - FreeBSD Platform
- `linux` - Linux Platform
- `openbsd` - OpenBSD platform
- `sunos` - SunOS platform
- `win32` - Windows platform
  https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processplatform

When using both combinations of values there are: `11 architectures x 7 platforms = 77 possible combinations`. It's not realistic to build/test/support all of them.

What are the most common CPU architectures and system platforms for personal computers?

(Would be great if you have computer sales data, market share, website viewer statistics, e.g. https://gs.statcounter.com/os-market-share)

Comment: Look at any mainstream computer store: all the mainstream retail computers you can buy are x86-64, except for recent AArch64 Macs.  Some RISC-V and other AArch64 systems exist, but personal computers based on PowerPC are ancient macs, and SGI workstations with MIPS CPUs are even older.  So the "most common" is pretty easy to account for; the question is whether you care about any "somewhat less common" systems.  Anyway, this kind of moving-target current-popularity question is not a great fit for Stack Overflow, maybe even off topic.

Comment: x64 (Intel/AMD/Older Mac), AArch64 (Mac M1) is the most popular for Personal Computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`x64`** (Intel/AMD/Older Mac),

**`AArch64`** (Mac M1) is the most popular for Personal Computer,

in the enterprise world:

**`x64`**, **`ppc64`** and **`s390x`** are also considered widely spread,

it's worth mentioning that arm64 is usually implemented in `smartphones` and `tablets`

Comment: I ended up supporting 1 x Architecture `x64`, combined with 3 x Platforms:  `darwin` mac, `linux` and `win32` for my desktop application

Comment: `AArch64` is used on most android devices, is 64 bits arm cpu.